# Draw and Clear String over a Control C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, drawstring

After some search at Google I had some examples but none of them gave me what I need.

I need to write a String (`WriteString()`) into a Control in WinForm on a `ButtonClick` and I need to update that Draw, because i'm trying to write the Date into the Control, the System Date.

So each time the user clicks on that Button the `DateTime.Now.ToString();` should be drawn into the Control.

Bests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[draw a string on label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593675/c-graphics-drawstring-to-exactly-place-text-on-a-system-label)

this url will surely help you

the code written there is

```
void Label_OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  base.OnPaint(e);
  Label lbl = sender as Label;
  if (lbl != null) {
    string Text = lbl.Text;
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    if (myShowShadow) { // draw the shadow first!
      e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, lbl.Font, new SolidBrush(myShadowColor), myShadowOffset, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, lbl.Font, new SolidBrush(lbl.ForeColor), 0, 0, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok ,it will work with the Label also worked with my Control ,but the only way to Update was to Control.Hide(); than Control.Show();

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a winforms [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) and a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) for that.

Comment: Yes but if i use Label into a Video Player Control ,the Label is Showing is' Background ,i need it transparent (The Background).

Comment: you can try setting the label [background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx) color to [Transparent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.transparent.aspx) but that may or may not work depending on how you're rendering the video

Answer (score 0):

Or you could modify the OnPaint method of the control to override how the control is painted. There is a method in the Graphics object that lets you write a string g.DrawString

Comment: Can you provide me some Examples Please ?

Comment: Here you will see one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx